# Why do you have to create a new Image to work with its Graphics in Slick2D?

Tags: java, image, graphics, rotation, slick2d

I need to get a rotated version of an Image in Slick2D and as the Image is not actually rotated when you call the setRotation(..) method, but only is rotated when its drawn in a Graphics context, I have to "draw" the texture of my Image myself.

```
Image original = image.copy();
        try {
            image = new Image(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            original.setRotation(rotation*90);
            g.drawImage(original, 0, 0);
            g.destroy();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
        }
```

So this code works, rotation being an integer value between 0 and 4 (0, 1, 2 or 3).
But when I remove the

```
image = new Image(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
```

it doesnt work anymore, and my question is: Why? 
It should work without it, the image is already there and one should be able to draw on its graphics, but it isnt, it is only possible when I create a new Image with the same width and height again. If I don't, the image being created is weird and messed up, way smaller than it was before. Does it have to be a completely "empty" Image when I want do work with it via its graphics?

Thanks for any help and clarification in advance.

Comment: The render method provides a Graphics object, use that.

Comment: @AnubianNoob You seem to have misunderstood what I am trying to do, I want to have an actually rotated version of the image, not that the image is rendered rotated (which is what rotate(...) and setRotation(...) do)